# Return different input after foreach for multiple checkboxes PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, input, foreach

I have one form for multiple checkbox entries.

I can loop through to grab the data using the foreach function.

```
foreach($_POST['competition'] as $value) {
    echo "Value = $value <br>";
}

<input type="checkbox" name="competition[]" value="comp 1">
<input type="checkbox" name="competition[]" value="comp 2">
<input type="checkbox" name="competition[]" value="comp 3">
```

This returns exactly what I need, however some of the competitions will have a input field for an answer.

```
<label for="text">Answer <strong>A, B or C </strong></label>
<input type="text" name="answer1" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="competition[]" value="comp 1">

<input type="checkbox" name="competition[]" value="comp 2">

<label for="text">Answer <strong>A, B or C </strong></label>
<input type="text" name="answer2" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="competition[]" value="comp 3">
```

If someone has ticked to enter & also wrote in a answer, how would I loop through and make sure the right answer would be returned to the "foreach" (providing they have entered something into the input field)

I would like to see

```
Value = comp1 - Answer = $answer1
Value = comp2 
Value = comp3 - Answer = $answer3
```

if something has been entered into the input field, return it when I'm looping through with the `foreach $_POST['comp']`

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what you'd like to see? Are you going for something like "Answer1 is 'some text' and competition for answer1 is comp1?"

Comment: sorry yes... I would like to see 

Value = comp1 - Answer = $answer
Value = comp2 
Value = comp3 - Answer = $answer

I'm just about to edit the question a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably going to have to break down and rename some of the fields here:

```
<label for="text">Answer <strong>A, B or C </strong></label>
<input type="text" name="answer1" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="answer_1_competition[]" value="comp 1">

<input type="checkbox" name="answer_1_competition[]" value="comp 2">

<label for="text">Answer <strong>A, B or C </strong></label>
<input type="text" name="answer2" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="answer_2_competition[]" value="comp 1">

<?php

$answer_keys = array(1, 2);
$answers = array();

foreach($answer_keys as $index)
{
    $answers[$index] = array(
        'answer' => '',
        'competition' => array(),
    );

    if(isset($_POST['answer' . $index]))
        $answers[$index]['answer'] = $_POST['answer' . $index];

    if(isset($_POST['answer_' . $index . '_competition']))
        foreach($_POST['answer_' . $index . '_competition'] as $comp)
            $answers[$index]['competition'][] = $comp;
}

print_r($answers);

/*
* Should look something like
* 
* Array(
*   1 => array(
*     'answer' => 'Something',
*     'competition' => array(
*        'comp1',
*     )
*   ),
*   etc
* )
*
*/
```

That's what I've got, but I don't like it. However, I'm not sure of the best way to approach this. More details on how the text and checkboxes relate to each other might help.

Comment: Thanks for helping, basically I have a system where the competitions will be published there could be 2 but there could be anything up to 20. The value of the comp will be its title. only a small fraction of the competitions will require an answer. I'm currently running through each competition when ticked and returning the everything needed, I'm unsure how to return the answer if any of the ticked competitions have one. Hope this makes sense.